# Intersection of *segments* in 3D using projective geometric algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

There is a relatively common technique to find the intersection of two segments in 3D, which can be found in page 304 of [Graphics Gems](https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Game%20Development/Programming/Graphics%20Gems%201.pdf)

Note that a segment is a compact subset of a line.

The technique mostly works, but special logic is needed to handle the 2 cases where the lines are parallel. One where they overlap and one where they don't.

Normally these constructions are much easier with PGA but I don't see anything explicit on the bivector cheat sheet that I commonly use for PGA.

So, given 4 points in 3D given in pair wise segments $(p_1,  p_2), (p_3, p_4)$

Can you:

- Find the intersection point if it exists (including in cases where the lines are parallel and overlap, in which case any point belonging to both segments is good enough)
- Return the closest points on each line in the case where the lines don't intersect, such as skew lines or parallel lines that do not overlap.

?

I have been toying around with doing the wedge of two lines $l_1 \wedge l_2$ to see what happens in those cases, but I am not getting anything useful.

Comment: Determining 1) the convex hull of the two segments i.e., a tetrahedron 2) the shortest segment between the two supporting lines (which hopefully will fall too far away...) should provide all possible answers.

Comment: This is probably easier in CGA which directly represents lines segments.

Comment: For two *lines* $l_1,l_2$ in PGA, you can detect if they intersect with $l_1\wedge l_2=0$ and $(l_1\times l_2)^2\ne0$. The first ensures they are in the same plane. If they are parallel then we can write $l_1=p\vee V$ and $l_2=(p+W)\vee V$ for point $p$ and ideal points $V,W$, whence $l_1\times l_2=(p\vee V)\times(W\vee V)$ which is ideal and so squares to zero. When $l_1,l_2$ intersect then $l_1=\pi\wedge\pi_1$ and $l_2=\pi\wedge\pi_2$ where $\pi$ is their common plane, and hence $l_1\times l_2 \propto \pi_1\wedge\pi_2$ making it the line orthogonal to $\pi$ through the intersection point.

Comment: @Nicholas Todoroff 1) You should transform this comment into an answer. 2) Which book or document would you advise to "delve" into PGA when one has already a background in classical geometry ? I only know the book by Hestenes.

Comment: @JeanMarie (1) This only covers two lines, but OP is specifically interested in line *segments*. (2) I put this in a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148470/projective-geometric-algebra-literature) because it's too off topic/long for a comment.

Comment: @Nicholas Todoroff A big big thank.